# SQL Problem i don't know how to change by queries on inner join

Tags: sql

I have a problem

I have 2, same tables. My select should show this two columns and the last one "sup_cr" should be counted.

sup_id, sup_name, sup_cr.

This is my query without inner join. But i don't know how to use a inner join in this query.

```
SELECT sup.sup_id,
sup.sup_name_en AS name,

(SELECT COUNT (sup_cr.sup_id_from)

FROM t_sup_supplier AS sup_cr

WHERE sup_cr.sup_id_from = sup.sup_id ) AS cr_numbers

FROM t_sup_supplier AS sup
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected result, makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a join or aggregation.  You can use a window function:

```
SELECT sup.sup_id, sup.sup_name_en AS name,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sup_id) AS cr_numbers
FROM t_sup_supplier sup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rephrase this a join using:

```sql
SELECT
    sup.sup_id,
    sup.sup_name_en AS name,
    COALESCE(sup_cr.cnt, 0) AS cr_numbers
FROM t_sup_supplier
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT sup_id_from, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM t_sup_supplier
    GROUP BY sup_id_from
) sup_cr
    ON sup_cr.sup_id_from = sup.sup_id;
```